# Robocopy Error 32 File I'm trying to update/replace is being used by another process

Tags: windows, process, cmd, robocopy

I'm trying to copy a local file onto a server using robocopy. This is my script:

```
if exist \\10.1.1.1\c$ net use \\10.1.1.1\c$ /delete
net use Z: \\10.1.1.1\c$ p@ssword /user:domain\username
:: first copy files to a temp directory
xcopy C:\dev\Filepath C:\dev\TempFiles\ /E /C /H /R /K /O /Y
:: then copy files from temp directory to server
robocopy "C:\dev\TempFiles" "Z:\Program Files (x86)\Insite Software\Commerce Integration Service V3.7.1.16264" MSD*.dll
net use \\10.1.1.1\c$ /delete
```

I realized that it's not working because the file I'm trying to replace on the server is currently in use on the server. How do I replace a file that's currently in use?

Comment: If you get error 32, the file *is* being used by another process, there are no exceptions.  Now you just need to figure out why!  The most likely reason is that the application the DLL belongs to is running, though depending on what the DLL does it might be loaded into Explorer or some third-party process. (There's also an outside chance the kernel has it open, in that case the most likely culprit is the anti-virus software.)  Process Explorer (available from the MS web site) may be useful.

Comment: But why would the files in TempFiles be locked? I just created the folder in the command line, there's no way the files there are being used by any process.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to overwrite a file in the target ? By the way: you might run into problems when trying to write to a program files folder because normally you need administrative permissions to do this

Comment: You can usually rename a DLL that is in use, and then copy the new DLL into place.  This isn't really safe; you *should* shut down the application first.