# robocopy Error 32: Unable to copy a file that I just created

Tags: windows, process, cmd, copy, robocopy

I'm trying to copy a dll onto a server using a command line script. However, I'm getting blocked because it says that the file is in use. This doesn't make sense though, because in my script I copy the file to a new location, and then copy the NEW file to the server; the new file has literally just been created, so how can it be in use? What do I do to copy my file to the server?

```
if exist \\10.1.1.1\c$ net use \\10.1.1.1\c$ /delete
net use Z: \\10.1.1.1\c$ P@55word /user:mdomain\username
:: first copy files to a temp directory
xcopy C:\dev\Filepath C:\dev\TempFiles\ /E /C /H /R /K /O /Y
:: then copy files from temp directory to server
robocopy "C:\dev\TempFiles" "Z:\Program Files (x86)\Insite Software\Commerce Integration Service V3.7.1.16264" MSD*.dll
net use \\10.1.1.1\c$ /delete
```

Comment: Have you tested if the **target** file (the file located at `z:\....`) is in use?

Comment: try this `tasklist /m thelocked.dll` and tell us state. Also you can use `psexplorer` from systernal

Comment: There is a complete thread that show you how to get rid of that. http://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Robocopy Error 32 File I'm trying to update/replace is being used by another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112307/robocopy-error-32-file-im-trying-to-update-replace-is-being-used-by-another-pro)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the file in use was the one on the server, not the local file. I used *net stop* to stop the service that was using it and then started it again after replacing the file.